# is there source code on github with a neural network that animates photos, making photos moving pictures like in a video

Tags: data-request, open-source, git

is there source code on github with a neural network that animates photos, making photos moving pictures like in a video? For example somithing similar on Deep Nostalgia (https://www.myheritage.com/deep-nostalgia?lang=EN)

Answer (score 1):

There are some open source projects that can be used to create animations based on a still image and a so called “driving animation”.

For instance “[First Order Model](https://github.com/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model)”.

It’s possible that my heritage is using such driving animations to animate the face in a certain pattern.